# Can React Context be used to provide a closure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there anything wrong with providing a closure to an app using React's context?

I'm exploring ways to provide an `onError` function to every page of my app that would result in an alert popping up on the page. Eg:

```js
function App() {
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

  function addError(err) {
    setErrors([err, ...errors]);
  }

  return (
    <OnErrorContext.Provider value={addError}>
      <Alerts errors={errors} />
      <WidgetPage id={123} />
    </OnErrorContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Alerts({ errors }) {
  return errors.map((e) => <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{e}</p>);
}
```

Where `WidgetPage` might be replaced with a router and many pages, each with access to the `OnErrorContext`. This would enable each page to add an error easily:

```js
function WidgetPage({ id }) {
  const onError = useContext(OnErrorContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id === 123) {
      // pretend error
      onError("failed to load widget");
    }
  }, [id]);
  return <h1>This is some page</h1>;
}
```

Another approach I could imagine working is pubsub and an errors topic, but for now I'm trying to understand why this approach would/wouldn't work, and potential issues with it.

Edit: Forgot to include a link to a working demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-dj216

Comment: This look like it should work totally fine

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, but it would be more standard to use an error boundary + throwing an error if I understand your use case correctly.

Comment: @Jake sorry, forgot to include a sandbox link. Added it now. 

Yes, it works as far as I can tell. What I was unsure of was whether this had some massive perf hit or other side effects I was unaware of that makes it an awful idea. I can't see it being much worse than passing an `onError` prop to each page, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @AntoineRaoulIscaros - As I understood error boundaries, they prevent the page from loading. In this particular case I'm looking for a way to render little error messages while still rendering the page (or most of it) regardless of the error.

Comment: @joncalhoun another way to go is to throw an error inside the component and wrap your component in an error boundary, then the error will not propagate outside that error boundary and you can choose what exactly to render in case an error was detected. you can see more here https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html
and an example by Dan Abramov https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/wqvxGa?editors=0010

Comment: @AntoineRaoulIscaros I still don't believe an error boundary will work. Every example I have seen either renders (a) the children when there are no errors, or (b) the error page if there is an error. What I want is the children to still render, but with an info message about the error.

An example might be Gmail when you disconnect. You see a "you are disconnected" popup, but your inbox still renders fine. You just aren't getting updates.

Comment: okay, cool as mentioned earlier you code is totally fine, no need for error boundaries if there isn't an actual error then just a specific state, I misunderstood you.